# How to properly set the path to input/output file?

Tags: python

I am working on part of a Python project and the structure is like this:
`project/some_folder/another_folder/my_work`.

In this folder, the file containing the code is `run.py`.
In the same folder, I also have an `input_file` from which I read some data, process it, and write the result to `output_file`.
So in `run.py` I have something like:

```
with open("input_file") as f:
    do_something()
```

and

```
with open("output_file") as f:
    store_the_result()
```

This works fine when I execute the code in `project/some_folder/another_folder/my_work`.
However, when I go to `project` and run the code using `python -m some_folder.another_folder.my_work.run`, I will have trouble accessing the input file.
I tried to solve this problem by using the aboslute path to the files, but this will only work on my machine. If someone copies my code to his/her machine, he/she still needs to modify the hardcoded absolute path.

How to set the path to the files such that I can start the program either in the folder containing the input and output file, or run it as a module, and others will not need to modify the path to the file when running code on their machines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the path to the running module and then create a full path relatively from there:

```
import os

module_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

input_path = os.path.join(module_path, 'input_file')
output_path = os.path.join(module_path, 'output_file')

with open(input_path) as f:
    do_something()

with open(output_path) as f:
    store_the_result()
```

Comment: `module_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` doesn't work for me. I need to use `module_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__"))` instead.

Comment: That's strange, if I use `"__file__"` (using quotes) then i get the current working directory, not the module directory. What's more, using `"__file__"` gives me the same result as using `"__some_random_string__"`. When you say that it doesn't work you mean that it throws an error?

Comment: In my case, `"__file__"` will also give the CWD, but `__file__` simply throws `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`.

Comment: Are you running it from python interactive shell? If so that's the problem.

Comment: Yes I am. I will try to run it in the normal mode.

Comment: On mac `__file__` results in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not explicitly specify the "input_file" path, Python assumes that it resides in the current directory in which you are executing your Python script. The answer given by Paco H should solve the problem.